# How to avoid that a component is displayed as possible value of its own linkage property?

Tags: delphi, properties, components, delphi-2007, delphi-ide

I've defined a component class which have a property of its own type:

```
  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FLinkedComponent : TMyComponent;
    procedure SetLinkedComponent(AValue : TMyComponent);
  published
    property LinkedComponent : TMyComponent read FLinkedComponent write SetLinkedComponent;
  end;
```

In the `Object Inspector`, it obviously allows me to assign the `LinkedComponent`property with the component itself but I don't want it can happen.

At the moment, I've accomplished my goal by adding a condition to the property setter but I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid the component is shown in the dropdown list.

```
procedure TMyComponent.SetLinkedComponent(AValue : TMyComponent);
begin
  if(AValue = Self)
  then raise Exception.Create('Can''t set this component as LinkedComponent');

  FLinkedComponent := AValue;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: The F prefix is, by custom, used for fields. So `FSetLinkedComponent` should be named `SetLinkedComponent`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thank you, I've updated the question by applying your suggestion. I know it's a side question but, where could I learn something about these code writing standards?

Comment: Search for borland delphi coding standards

Comment: @DavidHeffernan [Found](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10280#3.3), thank you again

Comment: You should create a property editor, what is your Delphi version?

Comment: @Kohull: Currently I'm using Delphi-2007